# For Loops isn't working properly with comparison operators

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Having trouble getting my code to log Scooby Doo! (as testing as I move forward in my code) Instead I always get the alert!

I have the user entering data of numbers in an array eg. `[1 2 3 4]` and I am trying to get the alert to pop up when someone puts extra spaces in the array to try again.

And if they haven't added extra spaces to log Scooby Doo!

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", myExcelFuns);

function myExcelFuns() {
    var userInputStr = document.getElementById("numbers").value;

    if (userInputStr) {
        console.log(userInputStr);
        userInputStr = userInputStr.trim();
        let userNumberArray = userInputStr.split(" ");
        console.log(userNumberArray);
        let result;


        let newArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < userNumberArray.length; i++) {  
            let newArrayValues = parseInt(userNumberArray[i]);
            newArray.push(newArrayValues);
        }    
        console.log(newArray);    

        //Here is the trouble
        let finalArray = [];
        if (newArray === Number && newArray != ""){
            for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
                console.log("Scooby Doo");
                finalArray.push(newArray);
            }
                
         } else {
             alert("Only one space between numbers please!")
         }
    }
```

Comment: `newArray === Number` will never be true

Comment: why is that? Do you see a solution?

Comment: `newArray != ""` is a strange (and buggy) way of checking whether an array is empty. Make sure the types of the variables you're comparing are the same. This condition `if (newArray === Number && newArray != "")` is asking whether an array is equal to a function and an array isn't equal to a string. Use `===` and `!==` always.

Comment: @DarioCharles `newArray` is an array whereas `Number` is a function. I'm not sure what you intended this expression to do, so no, I don't see a solution

Comment: am not sure why you want to check multiple spaces in between when you could just as easily do `userInputStr.split(/\s+/)` which will disregard multiple spaces and be more user friendly but you could do `let multiSpaces = userInputStr.match(/\s\s+/); if (multiSpaces) console.log('Multiple spaces detected')`

Comment: @Bergi I think the OP's trying to test if the array is only contains numbers. And...well, that's not the correct way in JS.

Answer (score 0):

This expression is wrong and it will never be true:

```
 if (newArray === Number && newArray != ""){


 if (newArray === Number && newArray != ""){
     for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
          console.log("Scooby Doo");
     // Here you'll push whole newArray everytime it runs, I guess it's wrong as well
          finalArray.push(newArray); 
      }
                
  } else {
      alert("Only one space between numbers please!")
  }
```

I've wrote your code using some features from ES6 to show you how easy is our life using these features.

```js
//Here you must pass a valid Id
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myExcelFuns);

function myExcelFuns() {
    var userInputStr = document.getElementById("numbers").value;

    if (userInputStr) {
      
        userInputStr = userInputStr.trim();
        let userNumberArray = userInputStr.split(" ");
      
        //check if some value into arrya is not a number
        const isThereSomeInvalidNumber = userNumberArray.some(x => isNaN(x))
        
        if(isThereSomeInvalidNumber){
          alert("Only one space between numbers and valid numbers please!");
          //here if it's invalid you can clear the input
          document.getElementById("numbers").value = "";
        }

        //map runs into your array and return a new array
        const newArray = userNumberArray.map(x => {
          return parseInt(x)
        })

        console.log(newArray);
    }

}
```

```html
<button id="myButton">
        click me
    </button>
    <input type="text" id="numbers" />
```

I hope it can inspire you =)

Comment: Key:  `===` (three ...) means "is ***exactly*** equal to."  Which means that not only the interpreted value but also the data-type must be the same.  Which here it is not.